# Javascript Tic-tac-toe, how to communicate a 'move' between modules

Tags: javascript, tic-tac-toe

I am a relatively new developer learning by doing in JS. I'm trying to create a simple TicTacToe game with vanillaJS.

Right now I have three 'modules' (they're really just object literals): `Board`, `Player`, and `TicTacToe` (basically just the game-state).

The `Board` has a `state` attribute, which is a 3*3 array, representing the TicTacToe board. It updates when its `newMove` method is called, and has a `isInWinningState` method, which returns `true` when someone gets three in a row.

The `Player` has a `marker` attribute, which is either 'X' or 'O'. It also has a `turn` attribute, which is `true` when it is that player's turn, and a `isWinner` attribute when the player wins the game. A player can `move`, meaning it calls `new Move` on the board.

The `TicTacToe` object has attributes, `board`, `player1`, and `player2`, and methods for initializing each of these. It also has an attribute `currentPlayer` which keeps track of whose turn it is.

I feel like at this point the internal logic for each object is pretty thoroughly implemented (though, like I said, I'm a noob and could be missing something).

However, the communication between each object I'm finding more difficult.

In particular, I'm not sure how to allow a player to move. The `Player` object has a `move` method (though I haven't written anything in the method yet), and the `Board` object has a `newMove` method, but I don't know how to connect them via `TicTacToe`, such that when the `currentPlayer` calls its `move` method, the `board`'s `newMove` method is called.

I hope this is clear. Here is the code:

```
// board.js
var Board; 

Board = {
    state: [[undefined, undefined, undefined], [undefined, undefined, undefined], [undefined, undefined, undefined]],

    isInWinningState: function() { 
        return Board.topLeftToBottomRightIsComplete() || 
            Board.topRightToBottomLeftIsComplete() || 
            Board.aRowIsComplete() || 
            Board.aColIsComplete();
    }, 

    newMove: function(newMarker, x, y) {
        return Board.state.map( function(row, rowIndx) {
            if (rowIndx===y) {
                return row.map( function (marker, colIndx) {
                    if (colIndx===x) {
                        return newMarker;
                    } else {
                        return marker;
                    }
                });
            } else {
                return row;
            }
        });
    },

};

module.exports = Board;




// player.js
var Player; 

Player = {
    marker: undefined,
    turn : false,
    isWinner: false,

    assignMarker: function(newMarker) {
        this.marker = newMarker;
    }, 

    startTurn: function() {
        this.turn = true;
    },

    move: function() {
        if (this.turn = true) {
            // move
        } else {
            // player can't move
        }
    },

    wins: function() {
        this.isWinner = true;
    }
}

module.exports = Player;




// tic-tac-toe.js
let Board = require('./board.js'),
    Player = require('./player.js');

var TicTacToe;

TicTacToe = {
    board: undefined,
    player1: undefined,
    player2: undefined,
    currentPlayer: undefined,

    startGame: function() {
        this.board = Object.create(Board);
        this.currentPlayer = this.player1.marker==='X' ? this.player1 : this.player2;
    },

    initPlayer1: function() {
        marker = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'X' : 'O';
        this.player1 = Object.create(Player);
        this.player1.assignMarker(marker);
    },

    initPlayer2: function() {
        marker = this.player1.marker==='X' ? 'O' : 'X';
        this.player2 = Object.create(Player);
        this.player2.assignMarker(marker);
    },

    newTurn: function() {
        this.currentPlayer = this.currentPlayer===this.player1 ? this.player2 : this.player1;
    },

    gameOver: function() {
        if this.board.isInWinningState() {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

module.exports = TicTacToe;
```

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mcve], providing a MCVE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `TicTacToe` object into its child object's methods. You can use it later to call back game updating methods in main object, as well as allow you to access the others object of your game.

**Player**:

```
  function doMove(game,x,y,marker)= {
   // you do move here
   game.update(x,y,marker);
  }
```

**TicTacToe**:

```
  function update(x,y,marker)={
   this.board.updateBoard(this,x,y,marker);
  }
```

**Board**:

```
  function updateBoard (game,x,y,marker)={
   //do some update board rendering
  }
```

Then in TicTacToe object, you just call `this.player1.doMove(this,x,y,marker)` and it works properly

Comment: That worked, thanks! I didn't have to pass the `TicTacToe` object to the board, but passing it to the `Player` allowed me to put moving under the control of the `Player` objects. I had come up with a solution already, but moving was a method of `TicTacToe` (basically your solution, minus the player's `doMove` method). But I prefer this way :-D